# Hashing with Python 3: Do I need to .encode() every string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, encoding, encode

I'm migrating from Python 2 to Python 3 and wonder if every string literal needs to be encoded now before you can hash it. Example code will run perfectly under Python 2:

```
import hashlib
string = "robots"
hashlib.md5(string).hexdigest()
```

using Python 3 however, it throws a `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` so I have to append an `.encode()` after each string or am I missing something here?

Comment: `string = b"robots"`  (`string` is a standard library module, bad idea for a variable name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hashlib` operates on [bytes-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) only and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) explicitly states:

> **Note:** Feeding string objects into `update()` is not supported, as hashes work on bytes, not on characters.

So any time you'd like to hash a `str` object in Python 3, you have to encode it first.

Comment: Because in Python 2 you have `str` and `unicode`. In Python 3 these are `bytes` and `str`. The concept of `str` changed, `hashlib` didn't.