# Why do I get a TypeError while updating hash object?

Tags: python-3.x, hash

I am writing a simple function that will generate a password and salt for later use, when I run this function I get a `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` what do I have to encode exactly for this function to work properly and what type of encoding to use `utf-8`?

Please explain in details

```
import string, random, hashlib 

def hash_and_salt(password):
    password_hash = hashlib.sha256()
    salt = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range (8))
    password_hash.update(salt + password)
    return password_hash.hexdigest() , salt 



hash_and_salt(password="hello_world")
```

Comment: Is the `.dec` a typo?

Comment: From the docs, `hash.update` takes a `bytes` object https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update Also, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37097391/12479639

Comment: Your code will function by changing it to `password_hash.update((salt + password).encode())`.  and removing the `.dec`

Comment: Man that's an outdated error message, there are no Unicode objects in Python 3, that is synonymous with `str` objects. You need to encode you `str` objects into `bytes`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Axe319

just changed

`password_hash.update(salt + password)`

to

`password_hash.update((salt + password).encode())`